# UITableView insertSections Memory Leak

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have a table which content I fetch remotely while showing a modal "Loading..." head up display, then I present the table when the content is ready by inserting the sections with animation:

```
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:
                                     NSMakeRange(0, tableSectionsCount)]
                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Inspecting this in Instruments shows a footprint in the `VM: CoreAnimation` for about 2.78 MB. This footprint stays there forever!

When replacing the code above with a simple `[self.tableView reloadData];` I have no memory leaks at all. Although it is just ugly to do reload the table without animation.

Also replacing the `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` with other animations or even with `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` does not help either.

Is it a known issue?!

Comment: Is this in a real device or the simulator? If the problem is only in the simulator and not a device, ignore it.

Comment: Are you wrapping that method around beginUpdates - endUpdates calls? Could that be somehow related to this?

Comment: @rmaddy damn you are right!!! No leaks on the physical device! What the h*** is that supposed to be? Is it a known issue?! I was going crazy for the last 2 hours :/

Comment: The simulator is just that, a simulator, not an emulator. It's common for some memory leaks in some of the frameworks. There should be no different in leaks in your own code though.

Comment: Great, wanna put this in an answer for me to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simulator issue. No problems on the physical device!

Answer (score 0):

try to add `beginUpdates` before inserting and `endUpdates` after inserting and tell me what will happen

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange: NSMakeRange(0, tableSectionsCount)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: How would such a change have any affect on a memory leak?

Comment: I don't know and so I told him to try ... may be Apple uses 'endUpdates' to finalise things in the background

Comment: No, it's perfectly fine to call `insertSections` without using `being/endUpdates`. It's best not to post guesses as answers. Especially when someone else posted the same thing as a comment well before your guess.

Comment: I read your comments to his question ... I did't think of that before ... Thanks @maddy !